# Update View Pager Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity, android-adapter

I've an activity with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter that contains two fragments of the same class (practically an activity with two tabs).
At runtime, I need to update both fragments layout with fresh data, after user input.
In particular a user click on a fragment, and the other one is updated consequently.
Any simple method to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Fearing angry backlash because I'm doing ugly things and am now telling about them:

Let your Fragment register itself in the Activity so when you need to reload you can just call the fragment reload function directly.

Probably less ugly:
Let the activity broadcast reload, and have your fragments register a broadcast receiver so they'll know when to reload.